# How can I read binary PBF and bzipped XML OSM data in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap

How can I read binary PBF OSM data, e.g. example.osm.pbf or bzipped XML OSM data
in QGIS?

Comment: The buttons on the left side of the screen allow the addition of layers to a map? Could you describe your problem with more detail?

Comment: I removed the part of the question which refers to Shapefiles since it's a simple matter of reading the manual.

Answer (score 2):

Layer -> Add vector layer , select file for .shp file extension (also know as shapefile). On right down corner is manu where you can choose ehat files are shown.

I think XML OSM only supported by OpenstreetMap Import plugin (which you can find in Manage and install plugin unders Plugins )

I assume that osm2pgsql shapefiles you mention are not shapefiles as i know them (.shp ending) and i dont have clue how to load them, if they are .shp them see line 1.

Comment: The XML .osm file can be added with `Add vector layer` as well from QGIS 2.0.1 onwards.

Comment: What about `example.osm.pbf`?

Comment: pbf works for me only for points. Maybe the dataset is too large for QGIS.

Answer (score 1):

Version 1.10 of ogr2ogr can read a PBF file and write it out to (for example) a Spatialite database, for loading into QGIS.

```
ogr2ogr -f SQLite -dsco spatialite=yes -gt 20000 --config OGR_SQLITE_SYNCHRONOUS OFF example.sqlite example.osm.pbf
```

I'm not sure which version of ogr2ogr comes with the current stable version of QGIS I'm afraid.

N.

Comment: Should be the same version, but I'm not sure about the parameters used by `Add vector layers` internally.

Comment: I have Version 1.10.0, which is what comes with QGIS 2.1 from Ubuntugis nightly. It's fast, it writes out a 512 MB PBF to a 2.8 GB Spatialite db in about ten minutes (on my system). For the whole of England.

Comment: On command line or in the QGIS GUI?

Comment: Running from a command line Andre. N.

Comment: Can you try the same inside QGIS? I did not suceed with that.

Comment: I don't think there's a mechanism for doing this in QGIS (yet). N.

Comment: @AndreJoost how can I use ogr2ogr in this case, please?

Comment: That would be `Add Vector layer` and `Save As ...`,  but it does not seem to work with large pbf datasets.